# Tankless 240V water heater in detached garage tripping AFCI/GFCI breakers in house

Tags: circuit-breaker, gfci, afci, tankless

We have two separate buildings, a house and a garage/workshop, about 20 feet apart, sharing the same electrical service. On the service entrance, there's a Siemens whole-house surge protector. The service enters the workshop where it splits up in a large junction box. One part goes to the load center breaker box for the garage/workshop, which has a 100A main breaker. The other part goes through PVC conduit under ground to the load center breaker box for the house, which has a 200A main breaker. The grounding system for the house/garage/workshop combo includes nine 10-foot copper-clad ground rods connected to each other (in a loop around the buildings) by 300 feet of buried 1/0 AWG bare copper wire, and connected to the service entrance with 1/0 AWG bare copper wire.

(It's perhaps worth noting here that the electrical inspector, when passing our electrical for final, told me it was one of the best-wired and best-grounded houses he had ever seen. There's no shoddy work on which to place blame for this weird issue.)

The house's load center is primarily filled with combination AFCI+GFCI circuit breakers. The water heater in the house is a gas tankless and hasn't given us any problems.

The garage/workshop is primarily GFCI breakers (no AFCI or AFCI+GFCI breakers). There's a small mud room in the workshop serviced by a small 56-amp 240-volt (no neutral, just two legs and a ground) electric tankless water heater on a 60-amp circuit.

Sometimes, and not every time mind you, or even most of the time, but sometimes, when I turn on the sink or shower in the workshop mudroom (thus activating the electric tankless water heater), two combo AFCI+GFCI breakers *in the house* (a separate building, remember) trip. It's always the same two breakers: The circuit for the server/equipment rack in the basement and the circuit for the bedroom receptacles. It's never any other circuits in the house that trip, and it's never any of the circuits in the garage that trip.

It might be worth noting that the circuit for the server/equipment rack has a very large power conditioner / surge protector / battery backup system on it, and the bedroom circuit has surge-protection-built-in receptacles. However, these aren't the only circuits in the house (or even the garage) with surge protection. The (AFCI+GFCI) circuit for the entertainment center in the living room has a surge-protection-built-in receptacle and a battery backup but never trips, and a (GFCI) circuit in the garage/workshop building has a surge protector / battery backup plugged into it and never trips.

I'm at a loss to explain how turning on a tankless water heater in one building can trip (the same two) AFCI+GFCI breakers in another building. Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: No neutral to the tankless may be the problem. Some units need the neutral for the contactor and electronics that control the temp, without a neutral any 120v controls in the tankless system will be dumping to ground as the return path, I have seen upstream problems cause devices downstream to trip and this may be the problem. Why only 1 or 2 GFCI'S tripping? They probably have a slightly lower trip level due to component tolerances.

Comment: Why do these rooms have a combination AFCI / GFCI breaker and not just GFCI?

Comment: *one of the best-wired and best-grounded houses he had ever seen. There's no shoddy work* You might want to allow for some flex on that, trust me. ***Nobody's* perfect and there's *always* another page in Code...** and overbuilding, while nice, is orthogonal to that.  For instance notice the water heater is 56A not 60A? *why* and what does that mean for breakering?  Hint: 125%

Comment: Do these electric tankless water heaters have contactors like an a/c unit? How is their on/off switching different from an electric tank WH?

Comment: Intermittent faults like this are much more trouble to diagnose.

Comment: @EdBeal: The electric tankless has only three connections: two hots and a ground. It does not have a neutral connection anywhere in the system. All of its components run on 240V; nothing is 120V (it's the same way with my 240V air compressor, which has no room for a neutral). Its instruction book also clearly says that it only needs a ground and two hots.

Comment: @JimStewart: The latest electrical code requires many areas of the household to now be protected by either a combo AFCI/GFCI breaker or by an AFCI breaker and GFCI receptacle: The laundry room, bathrooms, and kitchen are all required to have this protection now. The code writers are considering requiring this protection for all areas of the house. I made the decision to use AFCI / GFCI breakers everywhere inside after considerable research and considering the various protections these different devices offer.

Comment: @Harper: The installation instructions for the tankless electric water heater were very clear: 1) Use a 60A breaker, 2) Use 4 AWG 60ºC wire or 6 AWG 75ºC wire for the two hots, 3) Provide no neutral, 4) Provide a ground. It's a listed product, so code requires it to be installed strictly according to the instructions.

Comment: Nick I was providing an example of things I have found since you did not provide a model or brand. Also note a very heavy load such as this can create a voltage droop that can cause your device to trip as another possibility.

Comment: Perfect answer, but weird they listed it like a non-continuous load.  Maybe it has internal "back off" logic.  Now can you tell if it the two are tripping in AFCI mode or GFCI mode?  Can you measure any voltage sag when the water heater is cycled on?  (Measuring it at the garage would suffice, I am thinking of sags on the PoCo side.) What is the wire gauge between service and main house (I don't doubt it, I just wonder what you selected.)

Comment: Are the two circuits that are tripping on the same leg?

Comment: @Harper -- it seems normal for tankless electric heaters to be considered non-continuous loads (i.e. if you run your hot water that much, your electric bill will be so eye-popping from that that you will quit that in a heartbeat!)

Comment: @NickWilliams -- what make and model are the breakers/panels, the tankless heater, and the various downstream surge protectors involved?

Comment: My apologies for not providing model numbers and such. The water heater is a Marey ECO 110. The whole-house protector is a Siemens TPS3A03050 120/240 Type 1 Split Phase SPD. The wire gauge coming from the transformer to the service entrance is 350 kcmil (aluminum). (Then 350 kcmil copper from there to the large junction box, then 3/0 awg from there to the house panel and 1/0 awg from there to the workshop panel.) (1/2)

Comment: The breaker for the server rack circuit is the Siemens Q120DF. The breaker for the bedroom circuit is the Siemens Q115DF. The circuit breaker for the electric water heater is the Siemens QF260. The surge-protective receptacles on the bedroom circuit are Leviton T5280-W. The surge protector / battery backup on the server rack circuit is CyberPower PR2200LCDRTXL2U. (2/2)

Comment: @Harper: When I de-trip one of the breakers, just one of the two lights on the breaker is illuminating, indicating an arc fault condition (or, more technically, indicating unexpected neutral current).

Comment: @JimStewart: The two circuits tripping are on opposite legs.

Comment: With the breakers showing arcfault it may well be the large surge from the upstream water heater. when the contactor pulls in there is a momentary arc at this current level it may be enough to cause this problem. I have not seen this on water heater s but have on a residential 240 AC unit it was close to 8 tons, I got lucky by putting in a larger comercial contactor it reduced the effect and there were no longer any nuncence trips (a bit different as this was a 30/40 service basically 320a service that can handle up to 400 for short periods) all loads on 1 main panel.

Comment: Weird.  "Arc fault" and "unexpected neutral current" are unrelated things, it'd be like a car computer blowing a code for "misfire cylinder 1/low tire pressure right front".   One has a meaning in an AFCI context, the other has meaning in a GFCI context.

Comment: Are the two breakers that are tripping in slots located physically close to the connection in the main panel to the cable leading to the building with the water heater? Wherever they are it might be worth it to change these breakers to different slots. Of course, if you have this same model of breaker in other slots you could switch the wires and see what happens.

Comment: Could this tripping be arising from interactions between all the circuit protective equipment you have? The water heater sends out a pulse when it switches on and this provokes an oscillation from one or more of the surge protectors?

Comment: @NickWilliams -- which of the two LEDs on the Q1xxDFs is lighting up? the DF breakers have an arc fault trip LED and a ground fault trip LED, so they are interpreted differently than the indicators on ordinary Siemens AFCIs...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: That's a good question. I've never paid attention to _which_ light lights up, because these breakers came with a sticker (which I put on the inside of the breaker box door), and that sticker only shows two options: One light (doesn't say which light) means "arc fault to neutral or test passed" and two/both lights means "arc fault to ground or ground fault." Since it's only ever one light, according to the sticker, it's detecting an "arc fault to neutral." Still, I'll pay more attention next time it happens (it hasn't happened in a couple of days).

Comment: @JimStewart: I suppose it's possible there's some weird interaction. Hmmm. I don't know that there would be any way to detect/confirm this or fix it.

Comment: @JimStewart: No, they aren't physically close to the main connection leading to the building with the water heater. There are many identical breakers much closer to said connection, and none of those trip.

Comment: I have an Eaton whole house surge protector and on the computers some modest old Isobar surge protectors so I'm def not up on surge protection, but could you bypass say the bedroom surge protection receptacle.  It would be hit-or-miss trial-and -error.

Comment: It happened again today, and I was mistaken before. It's not arc-fault tripping (one light). It's ground-fault tripping (two lights). That changes things...

Comment: @NickWilliams -- try temporarily swapping the culprit breakers for ground-fault-only versions and seeing if the false tripping persists -- that will tell us if the DFCIs think they're seeing an arc to ground, or are somehow fooled into thinking there's an actual ground fault going on.

Comment: So both of these AFCI/GFCI breakers tripped again? Does code or good practice require a bedroom to have GFCI protection? If not, change the bedroom to AFCI only. Can you speed up the testing process by turning on and off the water to the heater repeatedly in quick succession?

Comment: @NickWilliams -- any results from troubleshooting this further?